# Realm : multiple write at the same time

Tags: swift, realm

**Context**

I have problems using the method `realm.add(object, update: true)` successively.

I'm making WEB requests to my API, and I'm testing the case where internet connection is disabled. When a request failed and I get the response, I add an `UnsynchronizedRequest` realm object to `Realm`.

**Problem**

I have to test the case where I have to make multiples call to my API, so I will add multiple `UnsynchronizedRequest` objects to `Realm`.

I only start the next web request when I received the previous request response, so the requests are well chaining, there is no concurrent requests.

When I'm making **only one** request and that it failed, the object is well added to `Realm`.

But when I'm making **more than one request**, **only the first is added** to the Realm, and the others are not added.

What is strange is that when I'm **using breakpoints**, **all objects are well added to Realm**. But when I disable breakpoints, **only the first `UnsynchronizedRequest` object** is added to the Realm, the other are ignored.

I think it is a problem with the `write` thread, the doc says that it blocks other thread if multiple writes are concurrent, but I don't know how to solve it.

**What I execute when a web request failed :**

```
class func createUnsynchronizedRequest(withParameters parameters : Parameters, andRoute route : String){
    print("Adding unsynchronized request to local...")
    let failedRequest = UnsynchronizedRequest()
    failedRequest.parameters = parameters
    failedRequest.route = route
    failedRequest.date = Date()
    RealmManager.sharedInstance.addOrUpdate(object: failedRequest)
}
```

**RealmManager.swift**

```
func addOrUpdate(object : Object){
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(object, update: true)
    }
}
```

**UnsynchronizedRequest.swift**

```
@objcMembers class UnsynchronizedRequest : Object {


// MARK: - Realm Properties

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

dynamic var id = ""
dynamic var route = ""
dynamic var date : Date! {
    didSet {
        self.id = "\(self.date)"
    }
}
}
```

I already tried to check if realm was in transaction in the `addOrUpdate` method before starting `realm.write`, this not solve the problem.

I also tried to catch the error with `realm.write`, but no error is thrown.

Furthermore, if I execute for example 3 time a web request et that is failed, I'm sure that my code is executed because the `print` in `createUnsynchronizedRequest` is working.

I really think it is a problem with `write threads` because when I use breakpoint to slow the code execution, everything works well.

**Example with 3 failing web requests and USING BREAKPOINTS** :

[image]

As you can see, using breakpoints, the 3 objects are well added to realm :

[image]

**Example with the same 3 failing web requests and WITHOUT BREAKPOINTS** :

[image]

But now without breakpoints, only the first object is added to Realm :

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: Without seeing your `UnsynchronizedRequest` type declaration I cannot be sure, since you're not modifying the `id` primary key in the code in your question, but you're most probably using the same key for all objects and hence consecutive adds simply overwrite your first `UnsynchronizedRequest` object instead of adding new ones.

Comment: Do they have a different primary key value?

Comment: I added my `UnsynchronizedRequest`class. I'm using `Date()` to define each **primary key** so the primary keys should be different as the objects are created at different date

Comment: Thanks. Both of you are right. 

In fact the primary keys defined via `Date()` method is the same for the created objects. 

I thought that providing a new `Date()` each time an object was created will be enough to set different primary keys for the objects, but this wasn't sufficent.

Answer (score 1):

As I created my `UnsynchronizedRequest` objects with the `Date()` method, the created objects had the same primary keys.

The space time between object creation is not sufficient to make a `Date()` object different than the previous created.